# Dev Tools UI dash-plotly using VS Code

Tags: python, plotly-dash, vscode-debugger

I'm Trying to debug an app using vscode, my current config for vscode is:

```
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run"
            ]
```

I'm running the app by:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_ui=True)
```

The problem is that the *dev_tools_ui* is not showing up at the bottom right or anywhere.

Any ideas?